# Change background color of ion-page element only, not descendent elements, in Ionic Vue

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic5, css-variables

I have an Ionic Vue3 app. I'd like to change the background color of the whole page. I'm new to Ionic but I believe the way this has to be done (due to the use of Web Components/Shadow DOM) is to modify the `--ion-background-color` CSS custom property rather than trying to set the value of the normal CSS property, so this works:

```
.ion-page {
  --ion-background-color: red;
}
```

...but this doesn't:

```
.ion-page {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Fine, so I do the former, but the problem now is that all elements within the page (everything inside the `<ion-page></ion-page>` element which use that same custom property value now inherit the same background color.

Does anyone know how to scope the change of background colour of the ion-page element such that it doesn't cascade through descendent elements? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution here was to use local CSS custom property `--background` rather than the global property `--ion-background-color`.  So the following works:

```
.ion-page {
  --background: red;
}
```

I didn't previously realise there were different sets of CSS variables for different scopes.